How do I change a SharePoint Online Highlighted Content Webpart Property from "this site" to "all site" using PnP Powershell?
Background:
I'm working with SharePoint Online and using PnP PowerShell to manage webparts on a modern SharePoint page. I want to add a "Highlighted Content" webpart to a page and then update its properties so it displays content from "All sites" instead of "This site".
Problem:
When I add a "Highlighted Content" webpart using Add-PnPPageWebPart, the webpart is added with default settings. However, attempts to update its properties fail because the PropertiesJson is either empty or not structured as expected.
Goal:
To update the PropertiesJson of the webpart so it is configured to display content from "All sites".
Current Approach and Issues:
I have tried the following script, but the PropertiesJson remains empty ({}), and attempts to update properties fail:
powershell
Copy code
# Variables
$siteUrl = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test1/"
$pageName = "Home"

# Connect to SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive

# Add a Content Rollup webpart to the specified page with the property set to "all site"
Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page $pageName -DefaultWebPartType ContentRollup -Section 1 -Column 1 -WebPartProperties @{
    source = "3" # "3" corresponds to "all site"
} -Verbose

Write-Host "Content Rollup webpart added successfully."

Output and Errors:
The webpart is added to the page, but its properties are not updated to display content from "All sites". PropertiesJson remains empty, and the webpart still shows content from "This site".
Questions:
How can I correctly add and update a "Highlighted Content" webpart so that the PropertiesJson structure contains the necessary properties, allowing me to configure the source to "All sites"?
Is there a specific JSON structure or another method I should use to set the webpart properties correctly?
Additional Information:
I am using newst version of PnP PowerShell.
SharePoint Online environment.
Any help or guidance on how to correctly structure and update the PropertiesJson for the webpart would be greatly appreciated!
What happens In the output:

What should happen in the output:

